# Unable to inspect iOS devices in Safari 8.0.8

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I connected my iPad device running `iOS 9` beta version to Mac Running Yosemite 10.10.5 and not getting option to inspect in `Safari 8.0.8` under Develop menu.

Things i did

1. In device `settings->safari->Enabled Web inspector and JavaScript`.
2. In Safari preferences on Mac machine enabled "`Show Develop menu in
   menu bar`".

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about iOS9, but for previous versions you needed to use new beta version of desktop Safari to debug beta version of mobile Safari. Probably this is the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am not even able detect from desktop Safari the iOS device with 8.1.3 version. With Safari 7 there was no issue. I am facing it after upgrading OS to Yosemite and Safari 8.0.8. Any idea.

Comment: Hey thanks Redek. I am able to debug with webkit now :).